# OnListItemClick issue

Tags: java, android

The following class is a handler for my listview populated from a DB. It works fine, but now I wont to start a new activity when an item is clicked. I've extended from 'activity' to 'listactivity' and I believe I need to implement an 'OnListItemClick()' method. I have typed this into my class but I get an error and no import option. The error is given as 'void is an invalid type for the variable onListItemClick'

Can anyone push me in the right direction please.

Code:

```
package com.example.sqliteexample;



import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class SQLView extends ListActivity {

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    HotOrNot H = new HotOrNot(this, null, null);

    setContentView(R.layout.layout);
     ListView listContent = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.contentList);

     HotOrNot Content = new HotOrNot(this, null, null);
     Content.open();
    Cursor cursor = Content.getData();

    startManagingCursor(cursor);

    @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
    String [] from = new String [] {H.KEY_NAME, H.KEY_HOTNESS};
    int [] to = new int [] {R.id.txtName, R.id.txtAge};

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    SimpleCursorAdapter cursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,   R.layout.entries, cursor, from, to);

    listContent.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);



     public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
            // Do something when a list item is clicked
        }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like your `onListItemClick()` declaration is inside of your `onCreate()` method. Move it outside of `onCreate()`.

Comment: Many thanks cloudymusic. This is what happens when i have a done of code commented at the bottom and forget the end brackets are below it! :( Thanks again, ill set this as the right answer when the time limits over.